# Issue with google api Google_Service_Exception

Tags: php, google-api, gmail-api, google-api-php-client

This is my code in service.php file :

```
putenv('GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=service-account.json');

          $client = new Google_Client();
          $client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
          $client->setSubject('xxxx@xxx.com');

          $client->setScopes('https://mail.google.com','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.modify');

          $service = new Google_Service_Gmail($client);


          $messages_response = $service->users_messages->listUsersMessages('xxxx@xxx.com');

          foreach ($messages_response as $key => $value) {

            $message = $service->users_messages->get('xxxx@xxx.com', $value->getId());   
            $message_text = base64_decode(strtr($message->getPayload()->getParts()[0]->body['data'],'-_', '+/'));
            $headers = $message->getPayload()->getHeaders();
            foreach ($headers as $key_headers => $value_headers) {

              if($value_headers['name'] == 'Subject')
              {
                error_log($value_headers['value']);
              }

            }
          }
```

IF I run this code from console using php service.php I get the subjects of emails without any issue.

But if I place the same code in my controller method let's assume User.php Controller having method `test()` and I place same code in this `test()` method I am getting this error:

> Exception of type 'Google_Service_Exception' occurred with Message: {
>   "error": {   "errors": [    {
>       "domain": "global",
>       "reason": "insufficientPermissions",
>       "message": "Insufficient Permission"    }   ],   "code": 403,   "message": "Insufficient Permission"  } }
>
> in File vendor\google\apiclient\src\Google\Http\REST.php at Line 118

I have placed the service-account.json in my controllers folder as well.

Any help or suggestions ?

Comment: Have you done the domain wide delegation part?

Comment: Yes, i have done that.

Comment: In this line `$messages_response = $service->users_messages->listUsersMessages('xxxx@xxx.com');` can you try to use the value `me` instead of `xxx@xxx.com`